# Primary key vs foreign key when fetching a entity and it's related data in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql, indexing

If I have four tables RecordProducts, Records, Products, and Defendants with RecordProducts having these values as ids to the other three tables.

```
RecordProductsId,
RecordId,
ProductId,
DefendantId
```

When I run my entity framework query to fetch the RecordProduct and the record.Name, product.Name, defendant.Name
and my query does a join, is there any difference performance wise if there is

1. no index on the RecordId, ProductId and DefendantId?
2. primary key index on all three as one?
3. individual foreign keys on both RecordId and ProductId

   - I understand foreign keys aren't clustered indexes but does that make a difference here

as an example, my query looks something like this

```
var recordProducts = context.RecordsProducts
            .Where(rp => rp.RecordId == input.RecordId && rp.IsActive == true)
            .Include(rp => rp.Record)
            .Include(rp => rp.Product)
            .Include(rp => rp.Defendant);

var recordProductsVM = recordProducts.Select(rp => new GetRecordProductsViewModel
        {
            Id = rp.Id,
            RecordName = rp.Record.Name ,
            ProductName = rp.Product.Name ,
            DefendantName = rp.Defendant.Name,
            ...
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it relational, PK on RecordProduct ID and FKs on the Product, Record, and Defendant. Performance-wise SQL will handle it fine. The alternative is to use a composite key in place of the RecordProductID. I'm personally not a fan of using them since a composite record can often be a worth-while entity in itself to be identified individually. I.e. pass 1x ID vs. 3x IDs when acting against this specific combination.

When using the `Select` to reduce your entities down into a view model (Good to see!) you don't need to use `Include`. EF will build the SQL and join on tables based on the data you want.